# Are github release notes store on git?

Tags: git, github

The release notes seem like a great thing to me but I'm wondering if they are stored on git or just an external storage system which github owns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently not: a release seems to be proprietary to GitHub and not a metadata attached to your Git repo (using git notes for examples).

At the time of this feature ([Release Your Software, July 2013](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software)), the blog post "[About Github's New Releases Feature](http://driesvints.com/blog/about-githubs-new-releases-feature)" noted:

> However, there's something that still bothers me. **It's tightly coupled into Github** which only allows us to enter the information into Github's Releases system.
>   We can't transfer the data together with our Github repo if we decide to move the project from Github.
>   We also can't versionize or collaborate on the changelogs through Pull Requests.

Comment: Any idea what's the reason for that (i.e. why they don't use git notes)?

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat `git notes` might be used only for the release note *message*, but not for the associated binaries (or that would increase the size of the repo). Since they have to store said binaries on their infrastructure anyway, they stored as well the release metadata.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat I prefer that to the official method http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/03/08/use-the-git-command-prompt-to-supplement-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: AFIK the notes are cloned only if the --mirror option is used otherwise they are invisible to the client.

Comment: Btw Gerrit uses the notes to store the review comments/messages  too which would be great to see on github too... that way we have everything stored on git.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat I agree. This is not yet the case for now. If it was, I wonder how you would manage the transfer cases (from gitHub to BitBucket or GitLab).